# Firefox 84.0 is changing custom file extension from downloaded file

Tags: http, firefox, browser, download, http-headers

My web application creates a zip file to download files related to a "Task" instance. This zip file can contain images, .pdf or .txt files, the filename created has the form "{taskName}.taskBundle".

To download the file, the web application use the following headers in the response (from Firefox Network monitor):

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="task1.taskBundle"
Content-Type: application/zip;charset=UTF-8
```

**The problem:**

Using Firefox 84.0 (Ubuntu and Windows versions), the browser is replacing the '.taskBundle' extension by '.zip', so the downloaded filename is "task1.zip" instead of "task1.taskBundle".

I tried to download the same file with Chrome (87.0) and another Firefox versions (83.0, 82.0, 80.0, 74.0) and the file name is correct: "task1.taskBundle".

Maybe should I add another header to the response to prevent Firefox change the file extension?

I can change the Content-Type to 'application/octet-stream' but the checkbox "Do this automatically for files like this from now on." is not displayed in the download dialog.

Additional notes:
My app is written using Grails 3.3.9 but I think it is not a Grails issue because the response headers are sent to the client as described before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're fixing this in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1684183 , but it'll likely not be before Firefox 85 (ie we won't be shipping a security / out-of-cycle dot-release fix just to address this issue).

A simpler workaround for your usecase would be choosing / standardizing on a specific mimetype for these "task bundles", along the lines of `application/x-my-fancy-application-task-bundle`, if you don't want the UA to treat it as a zip file.

Both Firefox and other browsers can decide to act on the mimetype (e.g. in Firefox's case, we show "Open in Firefox" options if you send `application/pdf` or SVG mimetypes, even for `Content-Disposition: attachment` responses, to simplify opening the content immediately). Chrome has specific [checks for `application/zip` when sniffing](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:extensions/browser/api/file_handlers/mime_util.cc;l=105;drc=1455a2a7973eeaa06dc14bd60aa582d41ceeef7c).

The regressing change here was part of a fix to handling web servers who send `foo.jpg` files with `Content-Type: image/webp`, where users complained that the resulting `.jpg` files were not, in fact, jpegs. So we added extension normalization for a number of different mimetypes. I mistakenly assumed that `application/zip` files would be, you know, zip files, and could be treated as such.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to report this on Mozilla's Bugzilla site (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org) under Firefox as I can't find a report that describes this exact behavior. It looks like they've broken something in the latest version (whether it was a bug or a feature is hard to say) as I noticed this behavior on a site with a mismatching Content-Type too.

Of course, if it was an intentional change, it wouldn't be the first time the Mozilla has ignored web standards to do things "their way". It still annoys me to no end that I have to use the 5-slash hack to get file protocol links to open correctly when the standards clearly state otherwise (see: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=992123)